# React child component does not re-render after useState variable is updated on each iteration of a loop

Tags: reactjs, use-state

I've got a React parent component that loops through an array - for each element in the array I want to increment the counter in a progress gauge child component that shows *"processing row x"* where x is the current row number passed from the parent.

The current row number is held in a state variable that's set up in the parent with the `useState()` hook. I'm passing that variable into the child component through the child's props.

The problem I'm running into is the child component is only re-rendered with the last state value set within the loop.

Simplified example here:
[Code Sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/sparkling-browser-mmvfd?file=/src/Parent.js)

I want the child component to display the current value after the parent updates it once a second; it should count from 0-5, but it's jumping straight to 5 after a 5 second pause.

What is the correct way to pass a value like this down to a child component so that the child re-renders every time the value is incremented in the loop?

Answer (score 1):

This is happening because you're using a while loop to time out each incremenet. This blocks the rendering, and it wont actually render until the while loop is done executing.

To fix it, you should use a setTimeout instead. Something like this

```
useEffect(() => {
  if (value >= 5) return;
  const timeout = setTimeout(() => {
    setValue(value + 1);
  }, 1000);
  return () => clearTimeout(timeout);
}, [value]);
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply - my example wasn't the best way of illustrating the issue that I'm facing. Given an array of results returned from a database query, I need to loop through the results and process them one by one. Each result will require a further API call and the results of that API call to be evaluated. The requirement, which prompted this question, is that I show a progress gauge that's updated as each row is processed so that the user gets some visual feedback. How would you recommend passing down values to the progress gauge that's in a child component?